# Formatting Certain Dates in Python for SQL

Tags: python, json, postgresql, date, datetime

I have a couple of string versions of dates, days and times from a JSON file and was wondering how to format them.

I want to format each one of these such that it is easy to work with in PostgreSQL

Here is the first:

```
{"time": {"Friday": {"20:00": 2, "19:00": 1, "22:00": 10, "21:00": 5, "23:00": 14, "0:00": 2, "18:00": 2}, "Thursday": {"23:00": 1, "0:00": 1, "19:00": 1, "18:00": 1, "16:00": 2, "22:00": 2}, "Wednesday": {"17:00": 2, "23:00": 3, "16:00": 1, "22:00": 1, "19:00": 1, "21:00": 1}, "Sunday": {"16:00": 2, "17:00": 2, "19:00": 1, "22:00": 4, "21:00": 4, "0:00": 3, "1:00": 2}, "Saturday": {"21:00": 4, "20:00": 3, "23:00": 10, "22:00": 7, "18:00": 1, "15:00": 2, "16:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "0:00": 8, "1:00": 1}, "Tuesday": {"19:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "1:00": 2, "21:00": 1, "23:00": 3}, "Monday": {"18:00": 2, "23:00": 1, "22:00": 2}}
```

Second:

```
"hours": {"Monday": "11:00-21:00", "Tuesday": "11:00-21:00", "Friday": "11:00-22:00", "Wednesday": "11:00-21:00", "Thursday": "11:00-21:00", "Sunday": "11:00-21:00", "Saturday": "11:00-22:00"}}
```

and Third:

```
"yelping_since": "2006-01-18"
```

The third isn't so bad and I think I was able to format it:
This was the code I used

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(data['yelping_since'],'%Y-%m-%d')
```

However I am having some trouble with the other two. If someone could please give me some pointers it would be much appreciated.

Please let me know if you have any questions

Thank you for reading

Comment: 1st and 2nd are not dates. they are 1st) multiple times on a non specific day (which of ~52 exists every year, give or take a couple) - 2nd) are timespans on another non specific day.  We need more contex - consider studying [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as to what is needed for a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

The first two look like json - try the link above. It will give you the idea how to work with it. In few words - don't parse json yourself...

Eg in Postgres working with json is as easy as:

```
t=# select jsonb_object_keys(('{"time": {"Friday": {"20:00": 2, "19:00": 1, "22:00": 10, "21:00": 5, "23:00": 14, "0:00": 2, "18:00": 2}, "Thursday": {"23:00": 1, "0:00": 1, "19:00": 1, "18:00": 1, "16:00": 2, "22:00": 2}, "Wednesday": {"17:00": 2, "23:00": 3, "16:00": 1, "22:00": 1, "19:00": 1, "21:00": 1}, "Sunday": {"16:00": 2, "17:00": 2, "19:00": 1, "22:00": 4, "21:00": 4, "0:00": 3, "1:00": 2}, "Saturday": {"21:00": 4, "20:00": 3, "23:00": 10, "22:00": 7, "18:00": 1, "15:00": 2, "16:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "0:00": 8, "1:00": 1}, "Tuesday": {"19:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "1:00": 2, "21:00": 1, "23:00": 3}, "Monday": {"18:00": 2, "23:00": 1, "22:00": 2}}}'::jsonb)->'time'->'Sunday');
 jsonb_object_keys
-------------------
 0:00
 1:00
 16:00
 17:00
 19:00
 21:00
 22:00
(7 rows)
```

To get keys of "Sunday" from your first example

, and just casting it to `time` is jsut adding `::time` to the end:

```
t=# select jsonb_object_keys(('{"time": {"Friday": {"20:00": 2, "19:00": 1, "22:00": 10, "21:00": 5, "23:00": 14, "0:00": 2, "18:00": 2}, "Thursday": {"23:00": 1, "0:00": 1, "19:00": 1, "18:00": 1, "16:00": 2, "22:00": 2}, "Wednesday": {"17:00": 2, "23:00": 3, "16:00": 1, "22:00": 1, "19:00": 1, "21:00": 1}, "Sunday": {"16:00": 2, "17:00": 2, "19:00": 1, "22:00": 4, "21:00": 4, "0:00": 3, "1:00": 2}, "Saturday": {"21:00": 4, "20:00": 3, "23:00": 10, "22:00": 7, "18:00": 1, "15:00": 2, "16:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "0:00": 8, "1:00": 1}, "Tuesday": {"19:00": 1, "17:00": 1, "1:00": 2, "21:00": 1, "23:00": 3}, "Monday": {"18:00": 2, "23:00": 1, "22:00": 2}}}'::jsonb)->'time'->'Sunday')::time;
 jsonb_object_keys
-------------------
 00:00:00
 01:00:00
 16:00:00
 17:00:00
 19:00:00
 21:00:00
 22:00:00
(7 rows)
```